# Redux observable epic with Rxjs issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

My epic is as follows

```
export const fetchSomethingEpic = (action$, state$) => {
  return action$.pipe(ofType(someActions.FETCH_LEADS),
    mergeMap(action =>
      from(api().get('SOMETHING'))
        .map(response => fetchSomethingSuccess(response.data))
        .catch(error => Observable.of(fetchSomethingError(error))))
  );
}
```

api here is `axios.create` which happens in a different file

Basically this was working perfectly when I had `rxjs-compat` installed. But trying to remove it and now giving me following error

```
TypeError: Object(...)(...).map is not a function
```

With `rxjs-compat` installed, where it works

I had

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

  "rxjs": "6.2.1",
  "rxjs-compat":"6.2.1"
```

Now I have

```
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
  import { mergeMap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

 "rxjs": "^6.5.2"
```

Am I missing something here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as below

```
  export const fetchSomethingEpic = (action$) =>
      action$.ofType(someActions.FETCH_LEADS)
        .pipe(mergeMap((action) => from(api().get('SOMETHING'))
          .pipe(map(response => fetchSomethingSuccess(response.data)),
            catchError(error => fetchSomethingError(error))))
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `pipe` to pass the observable to use `map` operator. Also import `catchError` to handle the error.

```
export const fetchSomethingEpic = (action$, state$) => {
  return action$.pipe(ofType(someActions.FETCH_LEADS),
    mergeMap(action =>
      from(api().get('SOMETHING'))
        .pipe(map(response => fetchSomethingSuccess(response.data)),
        catchError(error => Observable.of(fetchSomethingError(error))))
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, this produces error : `TypeError: You provided 'function (source) {
    return source.lift(new MergeMapOperator(project, concurrent));
  }' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`